# maximum product of two no in array(GeeksforGeeks)

Tags: java, arrays

I tried the optimized solution but unable to solve some errors present in geeks for geeks when submitted.
It seems to work for the most of test cases.

```
class Solution {
    int maxProduct(int arr[], int n) {
        // code here
        int max1,max2;
        max1 = max2 = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(max1<arr[i]){
                max2=max1;
                max1=arr[i];
            }
        }
        return max1 * max2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `-8,-7,0,1,5` is your array, what would be max product of two numbers in your array?
Think about this test case

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add a second if conditional parameter: `if( max1 < arr[i] || max2 < arr[i] )`  because you won't always find a new max, but you might find a new second max. Also with what Somnath said in his reply, you could also encounter negatives, so I suggest using `max1 = max2 = Integer.MIN_VALUE`  to avoid any arbitrary negative interference.

Edit: As a slight refactoring, remove the parameter `n` from your method and in the for loop's conditional evaluation, simply use `i < arr.length`